# Casting a `class` pointer to a `float` array: How does it work?

Tags: c++, arrays, casting

The following code compiles surprisingly to me. Can you explain me how it works? The point which I don't understand most is how the casted c-array perfectly matches the class members.

```
#include <iostream>

class ClassA
{
    public:
        float ArbitraryVariableName1;
        float ArbitraryVariableName2;
        float ArbitraryVariableName3;
        float ArbitraryVariableName4;
        float ArbitraryVariableName5;
        float ArbitraryVariableName6;
        float ArbitraryVariableName7;
        float ArbitraryVariableName8;
        float ArbitraryVariableName9;
};

typedef float Float3[3];
typedef Float3 * Matrix;

int wmain(int argc, wchar_t * argv[])
{
    ClassA md;
    Matrix mat = (Matrix) & md;
    // Matrix mat = reinterpret_cast<Matrix>(&md); // This one also works.

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
        {
            mat[i][j] = (i + 1) * (j + 1);
        }
    }

    for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            std::cout << mat[i][j] << '\t';
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;;
    }

    system("timeout 60");
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
1       2       3
2       4       6
3       6       9
```

Comment: This is *not* guaranteed to work. That it happens to work on your system is a fluke. It’s illegal C++.

Comment: @KonradRudolph got a reference for that ?

Comment: @MattMcNabb ISO/IEC 14882:2014. ;-) Less facetiously, a serious of variables isn’t guaranteed to be continuously addressable (`sizeof(float)` *could* be 4 and `alignof(float)` *could* be 8 at the same time). But I was actually thinking of something else which, on reflection, was wrong.

Comment: @KonradRudolph IMHO the C++ object model is sufficiently murky that this can't be ruled out. The only real stumbling block is [expr.add]/5 , however that section is not clear about the relationship between arrays and sub-arrays (in fact the term "array object" is not even defined by the standard); and since we started from `&md` I think we are licenced to move around within all `md` (but not past its end)

Comment: Strict aliasing doesn't apply because we are using a `float` lvalue to read and write either a `float`, or padding bytes (which have no restrictions), and alignment doesn't apply since floats are aligned for float .

Comment: @hkBattousai this is a *standard layout* class (basically that means any class which would also be a valid struct in C), meaning that it is guaranteed that there is no initial padding. In theory there could be gaps between each float (which must be multiples of `sizeof(float)`) , but (a) no real compiler would do that, and (b) even if it did, it's fine to write into and read from such a gap.

Comment: @MattMcNabb Yeah, you’re right. I had somehow assumed that the compiler would ignore alignment requirements inside an array but that makes no sense. I’m forced to conclude that the code is in fact valid (notably since the type is a POD).

Comment: @KonradRudolph I think it's unclear , some people do argue that [expr.add]/5 prevents the use of the pointer arithmetic that's implied by `mat[i][j]` and they make a good case (but not good enough!)

Answer (score 0):

Because your class of 9 floats and array of 9 floats are stored in memory equally:

```
1111 2222 3333 4444 5555 6666 7777 8888 9999
```

So when you cast class as array, it works fine. But don't do this with non-equal sized objects, you may get segmentation fault.